# Device Load errors when rendering an ARMeshGeometry using Metal

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, metal

I'm using ARKit with [scene reconstruction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/3521376-scenereconstruction) and need to rendered the captured scene geometry in metal. I can access this geometry through the `ARMeshAnchor.geometry`, which is a [`ARMeshGeometry`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/armeshgeometry). However when I try rendering it using my custom metal rendering pipeline, nothing renders and I get a bunch of errors like this:

```
Invalid device load executing vertex function "myVertex" encoder: "0", draw: 3, at offset 4688
```

Here's a highly simplified version of my code that I've been using for debugging:

```
struct InOut {
    float4 position [[position]];
};

vertex InOut myVertex(
    uint vid [[vertex_id]],
    const constant float3* vertexArray [[buffer(0)]])
{
    TouchInOut out;

    const float3 in = vertexArray[vid];
    out.position = float4(in.position, 1);
}

fragment float4 myFragment(TouchInOut in [[stage_in]]){
    return float4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```swift
// Setup MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor
let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .rgba8Unorm
pipelineDescriptor.sampleCount = 1

pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "myVertex")
pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "myFragment")

let vertexDescriptor = MTLVertexDescriptor()
vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].format = .float3
vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].offset = 0
vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0
        
vertexDescriptor.layouts[0].stride = MemoryLayout<SIMD3<Float>>.stride

pipelineDescriptor.vertexDescriptor = vertexDescriptor
```

```swift
func render(arMesh: ARMeshAnchor) -> void {

   // snip... — Setting up command buffers

    let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)!
    renderEncoder.setViewport(MTLViewport(originX: 0, originY: 0, width: 512, height: 512, znear: 0, zfar: 1))
 
        
    renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineState)
        
    let vertices = arMesh.geometry.vertices
    let faces = arMesh.geometry.faces
            
    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertices.buffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
            
    renderEncoder.drawIndexedPrimitives(type: .triangle, indexCount: faces.count * 3, indexType: .uint32, indexBuffer: buffer, indexBufferOffset: 0)
    
    renderEncoder.endEncoding()

   // snip... — Clean up
}
```

I can't figure out why this code causes the metal exception. It stops throwing if I cap `vid` in the shader to around 100, but it still doesn't draw anything properly

What's going on here? Why does my code produce an error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the alignment/packing of the vertex data.

Each vertex in `ARMeshGeometry.vertices` consists of 3 float components, for a total size of 12 bytes. The code above assumes that this means the data is a `float3` / `SIMD3<Float>`, however the `vertices` from `ARMeshGeometry` are actually tightly packed. So while `SIMD3<Float>` has a stride of `16`, the actual vertex data has a stride of `12`.

The larger size of `float3` (16) vs the actual size of elements in the `vertices` buffer (12) results in metal trying to access data off the end of the `vertices` buffer, producing the error.

There are two important fixes here:

1. Make sure the `MTLVertexDescriptor` has the correct stride:

```
let exampleMeshGeometry: ARMeshGeometry = ...

vertexDescriptor.layouts[0].stride = exampleMeshGeometry.vertices.stride
```

2. In the shader, use `packed_float3` instead of `float3`

```
vertex InOut myVertex(
    uint vid [[vertex_id]],
    const constant packed_float3* vertexArray [[buffer(0)]])
{
    ...
}
```

After fixing these issues, you should be able to properly transfer `ARMeshGeometry` buffers to your metal shader